# Присваивание IP DHCP через ARP

Tags: сеть, ip, binding, dhcp, arp

Подскажите пожалуйста. В коммутаторе Netgear M4300-52G развернут DHCP сервер. Необходимо присваивать вручную IP к MAC сетевых карточек, для этого используем ARP, но при перезагрузке устройства, или при попытке сброса IP на самом ПК не выдаётся тот IP, который был присвоен через ARP 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ARP тут при чём? Статические выделения IP по MAC прописываются в DHCP static lease или около того. Где-нить в первых трёх пунктах настроек DHCP смотри.

Comment: Если бы такое было в службе DHCP, я бы сделал именно так, но тут, как Вы сами видите такого нет...

Comment: Не используйте настройки ARP для этих целей. Задайте исключение пула и пропишите статические настройки на клиенте.

Comment: Я - не вижу. Если Вы дадите ссылку на нормальное описание настройки роутера - посмотрю (на сайте нетгира смотрел - одна реклама).

Comment: Вот похоже на то, что нужно: [How do I reserve an IP address on my NETGEAR router?](https://kb.netgear.com/25722/How-do-I-reserve-an-IP-address-on-my-NETGEAR-router)

Comment: Да, конечно! http://www.downloads.netgear.com/docs/m4300/enu/230-11595-03/index.htm

То, что Вы скинули...это не то совсем :(

Comment: Посмотрел мануал. В упор не вижу ни static lease, ни static reservation (в мыльницах статическое выделение именуется именно так).

Comment: Вот и я о том же... А почему в ARP нельзя такого сделать? ARP (англ. Address Resolution Protocol — протокол определения адреса)

Comment: Но не может же быть такого, что на таком умном коммутаторе не было данной функции...опять же вопрос про ARP.

Comment: https://www.downloads.netgear.com/docs/m4300/enu/230-11706-02/202-11813-02_M4300_M4300-96X_SWA_14Jun2018.pdf стр. 475-477.